# Hello I'm working with HTML and JavaScript trying to work on an approve/deny buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I have two buttons next to the data that the screen will show for approve or deny I'm trying to figure out how to make it so when the user clicks approve the Status column changes from pending to approved and the same for deny.
here's the JS part

```
let getAllbtn = document.getElementById("getAllbtn");
let Approve = document.getElementById("Approve");
let Deny = document.getElementById("Deny");

getAllbtn.addEventListener("click", getAllReimbursements);
Approve.addEventListener("click", approveReimb);
Deny.addEventListener("click", denyReimb);
```

and here's the html part

```
<body>
    <button id="btn" id="getAllbtn">Get All Reimbursements</button>
    <br>
    <table class="table" id="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Submitted</th>
            <th>Resolved</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>AuthorId</th>
            <th>ResolverId</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Approve</th>
            <th>Deny</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>hotel</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>TRAVEL</td>
            <td>PENDING</td>
            <td><button id="btn" id ="Approve">X</button></td>
            <td><button id="btn" id ="Deny">X</button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this alot by

1. setting a classname on the TD that you want to update (I gave it a class of 'status')
2. making Approve and Deny use the same function which just reads a `data-attribute` to set the status
3. use `closest()` along with `querySelector` to target the TD in question

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.status-btn').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.target.closest('tr').querySelector('td.status').innerText = e.target.dataset.status;
  });
});
```

```html
<table class="table" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Submitted</th>
      <th>Resolved</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>AuthorId</th>
      <th>ResolverId</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Approve</th>
      <th>Deny</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>hotel</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>TRAVEL</td>
      <td class='status'>PENDING</td>
      <td><button class="btn status-btn" data-status="Approved">X</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn status-btn" data-status="Denied">X</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```